# SortedList DataGridView Refresh?

Tags: .net, data-binding, datagridview, bindingsource, sortedlist

I have a listed sortedlist that I bind to a datagridview. I'd like when I add items to the sortedlist to be displayed in the datagridview. I'm using a bindingsource.

I was able to find one reference that stated I must use a bindinglist to get refreshes.

I wanted to make sure this wasn't possible before going another route. I've tried calling refresh on the datagridview but do not see the new items.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if create a new binding source when additions occur then I see those updates. The key is to create a NEW binding source.

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = myCollection.Values;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```